# Too many open files when opening and closing large numbers of files

Tags: c

I am running some code which opens multiple files to read data, processes it and then closes the files through an experiment harness. The harness changes some parameters each time one lot of processing is complete and then runs the same code again with the updated parameters.

When I run a small number of experiments there are no issues, and when the program exits all memory is freed. However, if I try to run a large number of experiments, the code always crashes after around 1000 calls to the processing code. I have checked that each file I open with `fopen` is closed using `fclose` in each individual part of the system, but the issue still occurs, with Valgrind outputting

```
==11892== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1030 in syscall open()
==11892== Warning: invalid file descriptor 1030 in syscall dup()
Could not access specified file: Too many open files
```

after around 1000 iterations, and `perror` giving the "Too many open files" error. Is there something I have to do to reset the file descriptor count in order to open more files?

edit: Looking at the `lsof -p` output during runtime, it seems that the type of files being opened is `DIR`. The files that I am accessing are inside different directories. I'm currently opening files with `fopen("path/to/directory/file.txt", "w")`. Is there something additional that I need to do to release the file descriptors that I've used?

Here's an excerpt of the `lsof` output:

```
lt-launch 12101 michal   25r   DIR    8,1     4096 3537225 /directory/reference/20
lt-launch 12101 michal   26r   DIR    8,1     4096 3537238 /directory/reference/21
lt-launch 12101 michal   27r   DIR    8,1     4096 3537251 /directory/reference/22
```

edit2: The offending code is as follows:

```
FILE *fp;

printf("Retrieving event data from file %s\n", filename);

if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL){
perror("Could not access specified file");
exit(1);
}

char* line = malloc(MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
char* lref = line;
double_arr* event_times = init_double_arr(DEFAULT_ARR_SIZE);

// Get data from file...

if (i == 0){// we found no events in the given interval
free_double_arr(event_times);
free(lref);
fclose(fp);
return NULL;
}
event_times->data = realloc(event_times->data, i * sizeof(double));
event_times->len = i;
fclose(fp);
free(lref);

return event_times;
```

edit3: Although this point is where the program crashes, the cause is actually erroneous directory opening elsewhere in the code. See my answer below for what the issue was.

Comment: are you sure you need to have so many opened files?

Comment: They are never open at the same time - each iteration opens at most three files, closing them when it is done.

Comment: please, post the critical part of the code...

Comment: Are you checking the return value of `fclose()`?  It would warn you of an error... most likely cause would be you're passing it the wrong descriptor - e.g. continually closing with the same file descriptor.

Comment: Without some code that replicates the problem it is hard to say. But if `grep -r SomethingReallyObscure /` works [without showing errors of "too many files open"] on your system [assuming your system has more than about 4000 files, which I expect it has since you are getting this error], then it's highly likely a problem in your code and in particular how you are closing files after they have been opened.

Comment: What does `init_double_arr()` do? Does it call `malloc()`?

Comment: The `double_arr` struct is basically a container for a double array with length. It does use `malloc()`. It allocates memory for the struct and the array which is is going to store based on the parameter passed to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program was crashing upon attempting to open a file, but the root of the issue was elsewhere. The files being opened were in new directories for each experiment, and each of these was being created using some erroneous code which called `opendir()` and then used `free()` to release the memory allocated to the `DIR` pointer produced. Changing the `free()` call to `dirclose()` solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you have too many open files, you don't close the file after processing...

The code you posted closes the file on all code paths (except when directly `exit`ing, but that doesn't matter), so.. I see two possible cases:

- There's an early return in the code you haven't posted which doesn't close the file
- You corrupt memory with some other code, overwrite the `fp` and because of that you not really closing it - you can verify this by checking the return value of `fclose`.